# how can i define local json file using angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

i defined local json but my ui-grid can not fetch data from it!

```
 $http.get('complete.json')
```

this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zIhoX3sucw5PaEGmm5bZ?p=preview

Comment: Hi, if you expand state and again expand male/female count, then it will display data.